# What determines how long you meditate for?

Tags: glitch-2011

I just unlocked Meditation in Glitch, and I'm having trouble understanding how it works. It seems that I've been able to meditate from 1 second to around 10 seconds. Is the time random? Or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Good question. I try to find a quiet place with no one around, but that doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your meditation duration appears to be random, but it increases based on your Meditation skill. How many people there are nearby doesn't appear to affect it.

Comment: and rainbows mean you did it for max duration!

Answer (score 1):

The amount of time you will keep the mediation going is random except that you can't hit your keyboard or try to do anything with your Glitch while meditating. You can look through your bags and organize things though, just don't try to chop, make anything, or harvest anything while meditating or you will lose it. Gaining meditation skills will increase your ability to meditate (minute plus even), and allow you to focus meditating on increasing mood or energy, as well as 'levitating', which lets you jump higher and better for a little while. Imagined Levitation is the only kind of mediation that you actually should be trying to move your Glitch for.

Comment: How can I shoot you an e-mail if you don't provide any?

Comment: ? I am not sure what you are referring to...

Comment: @Kateky: You have no email nor a website but I would send you an e-mail anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure what is wrong with my profile, my work email and twitter (website) should be there. You can get in touch with me at katey@stackexchange.com

Comment: No, no e-mail no website. Can you see my website in my profile? I believe the e-mail is hidden. BTW. I've a photo on my website, too. I hope you like it like your own photo!?